# Implementing API into Python program

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I am using Requests to communicate with a simple api.

The code looks like this:

```
payload = {'text': reply, 'name': varname, 'avatar': varavatar}
r = requests.get('http://example.de/create.json', params=payload)
```

However, the result looks like this:

```
{"result": "error", "error": "error_no_direct_connection"}
```

This might be a problem with the api but I'm not sure.
So I printed out the URL that Requests created (`print r.url`).
It looks like this: `http://url.com/create.json?text=Test&name=myname&avatar=http%3A%2F%2Fa0.url.com%2Fnormal.png`

To make sure it's not a problem oft the api I tried it with curl. The command works!

```
curl --data-urlencode "text=Test" -d "name=myname" -d "avatar=http://url.com/normal.png" http://url.com/create.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl option `--data` causes curl to submit a POST request, not a GET request. Try `request.post(..., data=...)`.